# make value from api appeare as chosse file inputs default value react js

Tags: reactjs

make value from api appeare as chosse file  inputs default value react js
i have  this input field i want to display filename  that i get from api  default value

```
<input
              
              name="Idproof"
              Value={details.Idproof} //how to add value from api
              onChange={FileHandler}
              type="file"
            />
```

make value from api appeare as chosse file  inputs default value react js
i have  this input field i want to display filename  that i get from api  default value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because of security reasons it wont be possible to set value to input type file. Imagine someone sets value to some important document/file in a computer, these can be submitted to server without user knowing this right?

Alternatively to display selected file, its good to make some UI section that show previously selected file/files and give user option to choose new one if needed.